# Eclipse xml validation

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd

How can I get Eclipse Indigo to validate xml against xsd's that exist in my classpath jars? Currently it seems that it is only validating against the web published version of the xsd. For example I have the following in my xml:

```
    xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire   http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire-1.2.xsd"
```

In Eclipse the validation goes against the document located at: http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire-1.2.xsd.
However, when I run the application external to Eclipse the validation goes against the xsd that is included in the library jar file on my classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use the XML Catalog feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog) supported by Eclipse.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLCatalog/XMLCatalogTutorial.html

Comment: That tutorial doesn't describe how to use an xsd that's included in a jar file, it requires the file to be in the filesystem.